# Minimum threshold for car accident

Tags: android, physics

I am using accelerometer to detect the car accident. I am having a problem with minimum threshold value is required to detect the car accident. What minimum threshold required to detect car accident.

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    float x = event.values[0];
    float y = event.values[1];
    float z = event.values[2];

    float gX = x / 9.8f;
    float gY = y / 9.8f;
    float gZ = z / 9.8f;

    float gForce = FloatMath.sqrt(gX * gX + gY * gY + gZ * gZ);
    if(gForce > //HERE IS NEED THRESHOLD VALUE)
}
```

Comment: This is really something you need to test and find out for yourself.  Mainly because it isn't clear what you mean by a "car accident".  A fender-bender might not hit your threshold.

Comment: It's a very good idea. But one thing to remember, if there is false situation occurs, then it will be annoying hte drivers. You might need to think of different scenarios with respect to the speed. Since I worked on Sensor listener earlier, we have to do lot of constraints to get it to a final stage... I love this idea, but I m not sure how it will be useful in real time.

Answer (score 6):

Based on Googling around, I'd estimate a peak acceleration magnitude of >40G would indicate a car crash. See this [this paper](http://www.nhtsa.gov/cars/problems/studies/record/chidester.htm) for a basic study of data during car crashes.

Alternatively, you could crash a few cars yourself and get some test data. :)

Comment: Of course, a fender bender probably has a much lower acceleration, possibly even less than an average brake. So YMMV.

Comment: Another thing you might be interested in:
http://www.wired.com/wiredscience/2011/04/crashing-into-wall/

Answer (score 2):

**Acceleration required to deploy airbags**

Around 20 - 30 G's.  Of course it depends on your definition of "accident".

Source:

http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/523539.html