# Detect Throw Gesture in Android

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors, gyroscope

I want to detect 'throw' gesture in Android. For that purpose I have to use Accelerometer(To detect Tilt) and Gyroscope(To detect Rotation). I am able to detect tilt and rotation but I don't know how to define throw to detect it.

Answer (score 1):

Dear it about your definition of throw. Please check that link because for detecting the car accident there is an definition for accident proved by some researchers. [Minimum threshold for car accident](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507156/minimum-threshold-for-car-accident) So, you have to define the throw and accelerometer will be used to detect such as process.

Comment: How can I define throw? Can you please help me?

Comment: have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507156/minimum-threshold-for-car-accident ??

Comment: Hi Umar, I have checked this link even then I am not able to solve my problem. I have to define throw motion. Throw motion has specific angle and position. I am not able to define it